# How to mock the input dir for my unit test?

Tags: python, python-2.7, unit-testing, mocking

Related to a earlier question of mine: [How to unit test a method that calculates the size of a dir?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38076616/how-to-unit-test-a-method-that-calculates-the-size-of-a-dir?noredirect=1#comment63591038_38076616)
I want to unit test this function:

```
def get_dir_size(dir_path):
    """Determine the size of a dir.

    This function also takes into account the allocated size of
    directories (4096 bytes).

    Note: The function may crash on symlinks with something like:
    OSError: [Errno 40] Too many levels of symbolic links

    :param dir_path (str): path to the directory
    :return: size in bytes.
    """
    tot_size = 0
    for (root_path, dirnames, filenames) in os.walk(dir_path):
        for f in filenames:
            fpath = os.path.join(root_path, f)
            tot_size += os.path.getsize(fpath)
        tot_size += os.path.getsize(root_path)
    return tot_size
```

So from what I understood I have to mock the `os.walk` function

```
import threedi_utils

@mock.patch('threedi_utils.files.os.walk')
def test_get_dir_size_can_get_dir_size(self, mock_walk):
    mock_walk.return_value(5000)
    size = threedi_utils.files.get_dir_size(self.test_path)
    self.assertEqual(size, 5000)
```

But `mock_walk.return_value(5000)` goes without effect as my test fails

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/vagrant/.buildout/eggs/mock-1.3.0-py2.7.egg/mock/mock.py", line 1305, in patched
    return func(*args, **keywargs)
  File "/srv/lib/threedi_utils/tests/test_files.py", line 55, in test_get_dir_size_can_get_dir_size
    self.assertEqual(size, 5000)
AssertionError: 0 != 5000
```

What am I missing?

Answer (score -1):

Ok, I was heading down the wrong path. Should have mocked the `os.path.getsize()` method. Plus, the return value needs to be provided like this `.return_value = 5000`

```
@mock.patch('threedi_utils.files.os.path.getsize')
def test_get_dir_size_can_get_dir_size(self, mock_size):
    mock_size.return_value = 50
    size = threedi_utils.files.get_dir_size(self.test_path)
    self.assertEqual(size, 750)
    self.tearDown()
```

Comment: That makes absolutely no sense. If you mock out the whole of `get_dir_size`, **what exactly are you testing?!** All you're testing here is that your mock returns the value you just told it to. If you want to mock out `os.walk`, you need the mock to return what that function actually would, so that you can see whether your function does the right thing with it.

Comment: Haha, I see! You want to transform your comment into an answer that can guide me into the right direction?

Comment: Instead, I'd suggest you [read the docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html#os.walk) (or just *run the function you're mocking*) and write a `return_value` that actually represents what you're expecting to get back. That's the very basis of mocking. The [`unittest.mock`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/unittest.mock.html) docs also have plenty of examples.

Comment: I just wanted to be able to grant you some credit for it.